# Transpose Data from excel to SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

Here's my excel sheet: containing data about testresults in different quarters

```
ID  Q1Age   Q1-Result1  Q1-result2  Q2Age Q2-Result1  Q2-result2
1    4        8           9          4       10      10
2    5        9           10         6        9       5
```

How can i transform the above excel into following format using ssis?
I plan to have a flag that indicates the Quarter as Q1 or Q2

```
ID  Age   Result1   Result2   Source
1    4      8         9        Q1
2    5      9         10       Q1
1    4      10        10       Q2
2    6      6          9       Q2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a Multicast that splits the data into 2 streams. In each stream you then only return the relevant columns that separate the Q1 and Q2 data then use UNION ALL to join them back together. So one stream would have ID, Q1-Age, Q1-Result1 etc. and a derived field called source that added a hard coded value of Q1, and the second would have ID, Q2-Age etc.  The union all would then just put the two data streams together.

Comment: Greg, I thought about that. But, i do not want to tear my excel sheep apart. I want to use the same excel sheet. Since in my real data, I've got a lot of quarters..such as Q1-Q20.

Comment: You won't tear it apart - you'll just be interrogating it a couple of times.  If you'd prefer you can do a multicast and then only choose the fields you need in each side. Actually that would probably be better as you're only having to open the spreadsheet once to access the data.

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify. If you think this answer works then mark it as accepted so everyone can benefit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get your Data Into SQL Server using SQL Server Import/Export Wizard and use the following...

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT, Q1Age   INT,Q1_Result1  
            INT,Q1_result2  INT,Q2Age INT,Q2_Result1  INT,Q2_result2 INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1, 4, 8, 9 , 4, 10, 10),
(2, 5, 9, 10, 6, 9 , 5)
```

### Query

```
SELECT ID
      ,Age
      ,Result1
      ,Result2
      ,Source 
FROM 
(
SELECT ID 
      ,Vals
      ,LEFT(Cols ,2) AS Source
      ,REPLACE(RIGHT(Cols , LEN(Cols)- LEN(LEFT(Cols ,2))) , '_','') Column_Name
FROM @TABLE t 
   UNPIVOT(Vals FOR Cols 
               IN (Q1Age, Q1_Result1,Q1_result2,Q2Age,Q2_Result1,Q2_result2)
          )up
) p
PIVOT (SUM(Vals)
       FOR Column_Name
       IN (Result1,Result2,Age)
       )p
```

### Result

```
╔════╦═════╦═════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ Age ║ Result1 ║ Result2 ║ Source ║
╠════╬═════╬═════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║   4 ║       8 ║       9 ║ Q1     ║
║  2 ║   5 ║       9 ║      10 ║ Q1     ║
║  1 ║   4 ║      10 ║      10 ║ Q2     ║
║  2 ║   6 ║       9 ║       5 ║ Q2     ║
╚════╩═════╩═════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: it has a tag of SQL Server, doesn't it ?